# How do I fill with only one tr in multiple th table?

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I finding a way to fill all the space with one td in tbody

```
<table>
 <thead>
  <tr>
     <th>1</th>
     <th>2</th>
     <th>3</th>
  <tr>
 </thead>
 
 <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td>hi</td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

[image: example of table]
the above example shows that one image takes all the space off tbody

Is there a way to solve this with css?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the property `colspan` in That td:

```css
th, td {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<table>
 <thead>
  <tr>
     <th>1</th>
     <th>2</th>
     <th>3</th>
  <tr>
 </thead>
 
 <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td colspan="3">hi</td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```